# Is there any benefit in encrypting private keys to exchange over HTTPS?

Tags: encryption, https, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have two services communicating over HTTPS. The requirement is to exchange two private keys. Is there any benefit in encrypting these private keys with a public key (exchanged at handshake)? Or HTTPS is safe enough to rely on it for key exchange?

Comment: Well, private keys should never be exchanged, no matter how you do it.

Comment: That's for sure. Though it's a customer requirement to manage some keys offline. So we should download the keys on its mobile device. @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Answer (score 1):

However you do it, as a rule, keys should always be transferred in encrypted form.